# How to make text vertical scroll on hover by sibling element?

Tags: javascript, html, hover, scroller

I have a javascript that I found online that is set to scroll text automatically, but I'd like to it begin scrolling when an element is hovered, and stop when its not hovered on. Right now I've sort of got it - it will scroll and stop when the element is hovered, but it starts anyways as soon as the page is loaded. I dont want it to start at all until the element is hovered.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpgBWJ

```
code
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: which object/element in HTML you want that feature?

Comment: The title "Individuals"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JS, bottom, there are this block who will run function `initializemarquee`. So, all you have to do is to attach it with *hover* event.

```
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", initializemarquee, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", initializemarquee)
else if (document.getElementById)
window.onload=initializemarquee
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not very good with javascript..how would you do this? Thank you

Comment: window's _onload_, an object's _hover_ are all so-called **Event** which means when this event occurs you can tell it to do something (a function, to name it is `initializemarquee` here) via `attachEvent`. See the code above.  If you don't know all of them, no problem. Go google "hover event function" will see plenty of samples, then try them out at your codepen. I'm sure you'll learn and make it work.

Comment: @JoonJoonam no problem. please remember to click on the up-arrow and the check mark.